# using an assert with a contains in groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to run an assert with contains but am encountering an issue.  I have written the code below using groovy in SOAPUI Pro

```
def pieceid = context.expand( '${OneDX#ResponseAsXml#//Results[1]/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/PIECEID[1]}' )
def TrackingNumber = context.expand( '${OneDX#ResponseAsXml#//Results[1]/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/TRACKINGNUMBER[1]}' )

assert {!TrackingNumber.contains(Pieceid)}
```

The tracking number is 907598985733 and Pieceid is 1820480....therefore the Pieceid is not in the tracking number. However when I run the script it passes. do you know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: `{!TrackingNumber.contains(Pieceid)}` is a closure. It's always true (not null). remove the { }

Comment: What does it show if you `log` those variables? like `log.info "$pieceid  $TrackingNumber"`

Comment: I have amended the query and added loginfo: def pieceid = context.expand( '${OneDX#ResponseAsXml#//Results[1]/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/PIECEID[1]}' )
def TrackingNumber = context.expand( '${OneDX#ResponseAsXml#//Results[1]/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/TRACKINGNUMBER[1]}' )
assert TrackingNumber.contains(pieceid)
log.info "$pieceid $TrackingNumber"   .................however it is still passing and no info is being logged apart from Fri Feb 26 09:41:02 GMT 2016:INFO: .  I have attached some screen shots for info

Comment: @csman, where is the screen shot? And as per the previous comment, log.info showing nothing, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a trivial issue in this case.

Changes:

- replace `ResponseAsXml` with `Response`
- removed `{ .. }` in the `assert` statement, and introduced `( .. )`
- looks, you used incorrect variable i.e., `Pieceid` which is also not available - incorrect case.

Here is you go with the changed `groovy script` snippet:

```groovy
def pieceid = context.expand( '${OneDX#Response#//Results[1]/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/PIECEID[1]}' )
def trackingNumber = context.expand( '${OneDX#Response#//Results[1]/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/TRACKINGNUMBER[1]}' )
log.info "Tracking number is $trackingNumber  and Piece Id is $pieceid"
assert (!trackingNumber.contains(pieceid)), "Tracking number contains Pieceid"
```

You should be able to see the data of both variables in the log as well.

I would also like to recommend you *not to use indexes* in the `xpath`. Understand that might be auto generated by the tool. The reason being that if nodes come in different order, that will break your existing assertions for later test executions.

Comment: @csman, would you mind accepting it as an answer if that resolves?